# How does the associations work? cakephp 3.x

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.0

i started learning new cakephp 3.x. 
i want to do this :

```
$data = $this->users->find('all');//i want to get user title name
debug($data->toArray());//but i use associations. It is not join.
```

my associations code:

```
    use Cake\ORM\Table;
    use Cake\Validation\Validator;

    class UserTitlesTable extends Table
    {
        public function initialize(array $config) {
            $this->table('user_titles');
            $this->hasMany('Users');
        }
    }

    use Cake\ORM\Table;
    use Cake\Validation\Validator;
    use Cake\ORM\Query;

    class UsersTable extends Table
    {
        public function initialize(array $config) {
            $this->table('users');
            $this->hasOne('UserTitles');
        }
    }
```

my table name and rows name: table = users, Row = user_title_id, table = user_titles Row = id

i don't write join. how do i auto join.

Comment: Please refer to docs: [Eager Loading Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations). You have to **contain** associations you want in result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you need read the documentation how this [works](http://joshbenner.me/blog/understanding-cakephp-associations/). the problem is the association see you have:

> User hasOne UserTitles,    ok user has one title.
>
> UserTitles hasMany User,   titles hasMany this does not represent a relation.
>
> > bad association

you'are saying this:

> table user rows: id, user_title_id
>
> table user_titles rows: id, user_id

and this should not happen

should be:

> User hasOne UserTitles,  ok user has one title
>
> UserTitles belongsTo User, or you can use BelongsToMany if if this is required.

now in your table:

> table user rows: id
>
> table user_titles rows: id, user_id

```
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UserTitlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->table('user_titles');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey(['id', 'user_id']);
        $this->belongsTo('Outputs', [
          'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
          'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
    }
}

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\Query;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->hasOne('UserTitles', [
          'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

and with this relation this should be work

```
$data = $this->Users->UserTitles->find('all')->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks Bro :) this is link. very good :) i am understand. $this->Users->find('all')->contain(['UserTitles']);